# How to use vue-socket.io + vuex for realtime?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, socket.io, vuex

**I have a feed, where users can vote the posts**

**Server > node,express,socket.io v2.3.0**

Server > app.js

```
client.on('connection', socket =>{
    socket.emit('success', {message: 'Server Accecpting Connections'});
    // CLients connected
        client.clients((error, clients) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(`<----- users connected ->`)
            console.log(clients);
            console.log(' ');
        })
    // Disconnected user
    socket.on('disconnect',() =>{
        console.log(`user disconnected  ---> ${socket.id}`);
        console.log(' ');
    })            
})
```

Server > votePost.js

```
    const votePost = function(client){
        client.on('connection', socket =>{
            socket.on('votePost',async post =>{
                try {
    // logic
    socket.emit('postVoted', {updatedPost})
    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
module.exports = votePost
```

**Client > vue CLI,vuex,socket.io v2.3.0,vue-socket.io v3.0.7**

Client > main.js "Configuration:"

```
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import SocketIO from "socket.io-client"
  Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: SocketIO('http://localhost:3000'), //options object is Optional
    vuex: {
      store,
      actionPrefix: "SOCKET_",
      mutationPrefix: "SOCKET_"
    }
  })
  );
```

Testing connection to server on **post** vuex module inside actions **Receive succesfuly message from server (all connected sockets see this message)**

```
"SOCKET_success"(state, server) {
    console.log(server.message);
},
```

Emiting data to server from a component, inside methods:

```
createVote(data){
    const post = {SOMEPOSTDATA}
    this.$socket.emit('votePost', post)
},
```

Receiving data created from server: **vuex post module (inside of actions)**

```
"SOCKET_updatedPost"({commit,state}, server) {
    state.post = server.updatedPost
},
```

At this point, im receiving the post updated from the server and updating my state where i see updated. **BUT** i need to every use see the updated post too

**Why is this happening? what im missing?, all users suppose to see the changes when someone updates it**

Answer (score 1):

It's quite unclear what you're trying to do, but if i understand correctly, you want the "created" event to be emitted to all sockets, after one socket triggers the "create" event. If so:

```
 socket.on('create',(name)=> {
        io.of('/').emit('created', {name})            
    })
```

Problem is, that for some reason you're registering the "connection" event within some "create" function, which doesn't seem to make much sense. Your io.on('connection') needs to be registered once, in some high level module, and within its scope you need to register all specific events for the connecting socket. I don't have your full code, so i can't say, but this is something you need to look at.

Comment: hello @i.brod excuse me for the explanation, i just want if a user create a new name, every user see it, like a chat, that created event its the new data,when it comes to the client, is has to update it to everyone, by the way, im going to check that double on.connection event, this can create duplicate? do you have any discord or whatsapp?

Comment: We can communicate here...Can you explain what calls the create function you have? your on('create') event registration needs to be outside of this function. Within the event handler, you can call this "create" function..

Comment: I'll update question for you to see it clearly, give me a minute

Comment: dude, i found the problem!, check my answer. But i have the same doubt as you with creating 2 connections, any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The problem is that i was using

```
**socket.emit('postVoted', {updatedPost})**
```

Where socket.emit Means that the updated data its comming to the user who created that action, but changing that event to:

```
**io.sockets.emit**
```

This way every use gets the updated data.

**Clearly im not expert with socketio,any good course about sockets? thanks**

**NOTE :** I have seriues doubts about using 2 .on('connection') methods, any advice on how to module this?

Comment: on('connection) should be defined once. it's not a socket event, but an IO event. put it in the upper most module(or some dedicated socketIO config module..), where you setup your socketio .   Regarding a course: i recommend taking Andrew Mead's nodejs course on Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-nodejs-developer-course-2/ There is a module there about socketio

Comment: I recommend taking the entire node course, not just the socketio section, you can learn a lot of useful stuff there.